# Trying to use from "Systems.Windows.Forms" so I can read from Clipboard in my C# test App

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

Having a bit of a tough time setting in **Visual Studio 2019** Community Edition for a C# test program the reference to use `Windows.System.Forms` in order to have access to the class `Clipboard` so I can set and get text information from the Windows 10 desktop clipboard.

When I go to add the reference, I cannot find `Windows.System.Forms`, instead I see `Windows_System_Forms`. I tried to include it as a reference and I got:

> Warning   MSB3290 Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.

How can I include `System.Windows.Forms` so the code below will work?

```
[Then(@"validation text is ""(.*)""")]
public void ThenTestIs(string res)
{
    // Setup waiting for test selectors to render
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));

    string xpath = (string)Properties.MflixXpaths.Default["mflix_result"];
    xpath = xpath.Replace("TEST", testName);

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Click();
    string val = Clipboard.GetText();
    Assert.AreEqual(val, res);
}
```

Comment: What unit test framework are you using? What target framework is set for the unit test project?

Comment: There are some third-party libraries that might make this easier, like: https://github.com/CopyText/TextCopy

Comment: It is a SpecFlow/Selenium/MsTest test that I wrote for self edification.  I will check out that library and hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: Just installed and it did the trick, works like a charm.  Thank you this was a great solution.