# Warning MSB3290 Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I am using visual studio 2019 C# console application and I am facing this issue. How can I fix this issue?

Warning MSB3290 Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}" Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62176685, although the logic of the proposed solution in the comments eludes me.

Comment: Try adding an actual, first-class reference to the project by adding `System.Windows.Forms` to your assembly references.